# When sending a file with a WiFi adapter, the number of packets sent according to Powershell is much lower than the expected value

Tags: windows, powershell, wifi, packet-capture

I use Windows 10 and a D-Link WiFi adapter. I have tried with a TP-Link adapter and the results are similar.
On the WiFi adapter I have disabled all protocols except IPv4.

I start the Wireshark capture, connect the Wi-Fi adapter and after a few seconds the captured packets are:

```
Wireshark: 688 packets captured
```

Statistics with Powershell:

```
ifAlias                  : Wi-Fi 2
InterfaceAlias           : Wi-Fi 2
ifDesc                   : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
Caption                  : MSFT_NetAdapterStatisticsSettingData 'D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)'
Description              : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
ElementName              : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
InstanceID               : {65E2BEC6-47F0-49A3-B0DF-32CC24CD9888}
InterfaceDescription     : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
Name                     : Wi-Fi 2
Source                   : 2
SystemName               : 
OutboundDiscardedPackets : 0
OutboundPacketErrors     : 0
RdmaStatistics           :
ReceivedBroadcastBytes   : 0
ReceivedBroadcastPackets : 0
ReceivedBytes            : 1725
ReceivedDiscardedPackets : 0
ReceivedMulticastBytes   : 0
ReceivedMulticastPackets : 0
ReceivedPacketErrors     : 0
ReceivedUnicastBytes     : 1725
ReceivedUnicastPackets   : 14
RscStatistics            :
SentBroadcastBytes       : 608
SentBroadcastPackets     : 7
SentBytes                : 61688
SentMulticastBytes       : 60345
SentMulticastPackets     : 657
SentUnicastBytes         : 735
SentUnicastPackets       : 10
SupportedStatistics      : 4163583
PSComputerName           :
CimClass                 : ROOT/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetAdapterStatisticsSettingData
CimInstanceProperties    : {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties      : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

After sending a 10 MB file (10485760 bytes) the results are:

```
Wireshark: 8255 packets captured
```

Powershell:

```
Get-NetAdapterStatistics -Name "Wi-Fi 2" | Format-List -Property "*"


ifAlias                  : Wi-Fi 2
InterfaceAlias           : Wi-Fi 2
ifDesc                   : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
Caption                  : MSFT_NetAdapterStatisticsSettingData 'D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)'
Description              : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
ElementName              : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
InstanceID               : {65E2BEC6-47F0-49A3-B0DF-32CC24CD9888}
InterfaceDescription     : D-Link DWA-182 Wireless AC 1200 USB Adapter(rev.D)
Name                     : Wi-Fi 2
Source                   : 2
SystemName               : 
OutboundDiscardedPackets : 0
OutboundPacketErrors     : 0
RdmaStatistics           :
ReceivedBroadcastBytes   : 0
ReceivedBroadcastPackets : 0
ReceivedBytes            : 268254
ReceivedDiscardedPackets : 0
ReceivedMulticastBytes   : 0
ReceivedMulticastPackets : 0
ReceivedPacketErrors     : 0
ReceivedUnicastBytes     : 268254
ReceivedUnicastPackets   : 4222
RscStatistics            :
SentBroadcastBytes       : 608
SentBroadcastPackets     : 7
SentBytes                : 11214855
SentMulticastBytes       : 60345
SentMulticastPackets     : 657
SentUnicastBytes         : 11153902
SentUnicastPackets       : 575
SupportedStatistics      : 4163583
PSComputerName           :
CimClass                 : ROOT/StandardCimv2:MSFT_NetAdapterStatisticsSettingData
CimInstanceProperties    : {Caption, Description, ElementName, InstanceID...}
CimSystemProperties      : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

- Unicast bytes sent according to Powershell: 11153902 - 735 = 11153167
- Unicast packets sent according to Powershell: 575 - 10 = 565 packets
- Packets sent according to Wireshark: 8255 - 688 = 7567 packets

The number of packets sent according to Wireshark and Powershell is very different. For some reason the reading of packages with Powershell is very small. I am doing something wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Window uses timers to transfer the data from the app to the ethernet interface.  You probably are also going through a multi-hop connection and each hop can be a different speed.  WIFI the upload speed and download speed is different.